# css issue on hover- shaky effect

Tags: css, html, hover, anchor

```
<style type="text/css">
    .linkcontainer{border-right: solid 0.2px white;margin-right:1px}
    .hardlink{color: #FFF !important; border: 1px solid transparent; }      
    .hardlink:hover{
          background:url("/_layouts/images/bgximg.png") repeat-x -0px -489px;
          display:inline-block; 
          background-color:#21374C;
          border:0.2px solid #5badff; 
          line-height:20px; 
          text-decoration:none !important;} 
</style>

<div style="padding-bottom:3px;background:transparent; color:white!important; float:left; margin-right:20px; line-height:42px;">
    <span class="linkcontainer">
        <a class="hardlink" style="padding:0 10px;" href="http://hronline">HROnline</a>
    </span>
    <span class="linkcontainer">
        <a class="hardlink" style="padding:0 10px; " href="http://hronline/ec">Employee Center</a>
    </span>
    <span class="linkcontainer">
        <a class="hardlink" style="padding:0 10px; " href="http://hronline/businesscommunities">Business Communities</a>
    </span>
    <span class="linkcontainer">
        <a class="hardlink" style="padding:0 10px;" href="http://hronline/internalservices">Internal Services</a>
    </span>
    <span class="linkcontainer">
        <a class="hardlink" style="padding:0 10px;" href="http://hronline/policiesprocedures">Policies&procedures</a>
    </span>
    <span class="linkcontainer">
        <a class="hardlink" style="padding:0 10px;" href="http://hronline/qualitybestpractices">Best Practices</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I added a right border to the span that contain menu links. When I hover on each menu links, it also has some background. This is causing jerky effect on the whole container..
What is causing the shaky effect on  hover? I don't seem to figure it out--again..

Comment: can you make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3QdtM/) or may be you can your web address to see the effect.

Comment: It's not producing the problem you mentioned, may be you should use the image in the style panel for the hover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your .hardlink class has 1px border, and the same class on hover has 0.2px border.

Comment: Thank you! Wow! What a blunder! :)

Answer (score 1):

As Slave mentioned, you change the border size. Unfortunately less than 1 px does not exist. If you add `margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 1px;` to your hover css and put the `border` on `0px` it does not jump. If you'd like to keep the border, try a different (darker maybe) color for it.